# Mark 90 degree angle in tikz in german convention

Tags: tikz-pgf, angle

What's the best way to denote a 90 degree angle with german convention like on the following picture in tikz:

[image: right angle]

Suppose I start with something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
   \coordinate (O) at (0,0); %
   \coordinate (A) at (1,1); %
   \coordinate (B) at (1,-1); %

   \draw (O) -- (A); %
   \draw (O) -- (B); %

\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Related Question: [Insertion of perpendicular symbol at intersection of two perpendicular lines](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21752/insertion-of-perpendicular-symbol-at-intersection-of-two-perpendicular-lines).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'd do it with an `arc` and a `circle`.

The command `\rechterWinkel` takes three arguments:

- the point of the angle,
- the start angle, and
- the arc's radius (you probably want to have same-size right angles, then I suggest to hard-code the radius directly and just use two parameters).

#### Hard-coded radius

```
\newcommand*{\rechterWinkelRadius}{.5cm}
\newcommand*{\rechterWinkel}[2]{% #1 = point, #2 = start angle
   \draw[shift={(#2:\rechterWinkelRadius)}] (#1) arc[start angle=#2, delta angle=90, radius = \rechterWinkelRadius];
   \fill[shift={(#2+45:\rechterWinkelRadius/2)}] (#1) circle[radius=1.25\pgflinewidth];
}
```

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand*{\rechterWinkel}[3]{% #1 = point, #2 = start angle, #3 = radius
   \draw[shift={(#2:#3)}] (#1) arc[start angle=#2, delta angle=90, radius = #3];
   \fill[shift={(#2+45:#3/2)}] (#1) circle[radius=1.25\pgflinewidth];
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
   \coordinate (O) at (0,0); %
   \coordinate (A) at (1,1); %
   \coordinate (B) at (1,-1); %

   \draw (O) -- (A); %
   \draw (O) -- (B); %

   \rechterWinkel{0,0}{-45}{.5}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 8):

TiKZ 3.0 introduces `angles` and `quotes` libraries which simplifies this task.

A command like

```
\draw pic[draw] {angle=A--O--C};
```

will draw a sector line between line `A--O` and `O--C` with center at `O` and anticlockwise. Sector radius is 5mm by default but can be changed with `angle radius` parameter.

This sector line can be labelled with `label` or with new `quotes` syntax. The label is placed with certain `angle eccentricity` (default = 0.6) which is a factor to be applied to `angle radius`.

Next example is similar to student's code but using `angle` pic.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,quotes}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
   \coordinate[label=below left:O] (O) at (0,0); %
   \coordinate[label=above right:A] (A) at (1,1); %
   \coordinate[label=below right:B] (B) at (1,-1); %
   \coordinate[label=above left:C] (C) at (-1,1);

   \draw (C) -- (B); %
   \draw (O) -- (A); %

   \draw pic["$\cdot$", draw] {angle=B--O--A}
         pic["$\cdot$", draw, angle radius=3mm, angle eccentricity=.25] {angle=A--O--C};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The quotes library is not needed if using `pic text=$\cdot$` instead of `"$\cdot$"`.

Answer (score 6):

I have found a solution which uses `tkz-euclide` and used Herbert's answer to

[Defining a macro in LaTeX with an optional parameter in round brackets](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12891/defining-a-macro-in-latex-with-an-optional-parameter-in-round-brackets/)

to define the optional argument of the macro.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

%see: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12893/4011
\makeatletter
\def\rechterWinkel{\@ifnextchar[\rechterWinkel@i\rechterWinkel@ii}
\def\rechterWinkel@i[#1](#2,#3,#4){%
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\pos@A}{0.5*#1}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\pos@B}{0.25*#1}
   \tkzMarkAngle[size=\pos@A](#2,#3,#4)
   \tkzLabelAngle[pos=\pos@B](#2,#3,#4){\tikz \fill (0,0) circle (0.6pt);}
}% 
\def\rechterWinkel@ii(#1,#2,#3){%  
\rechterWinkel@i[1](#1,#2,#3)
}% 
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
   \coordinate (O) at (0,0); %
   \coordinate (A) at (1,1); %
   \coordinate (B) at (1,-1); %
   \coordinate (C) at (-1,1);

   \draw (O) -- (A); %
   \draw (O) -- (B); %
   \draw (O) -- (C); %

   \rechterWinkel(B,O,A)
   \rechterWinkel[0.5](A,O,C)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image: output]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution which does NOT need TikZ 3, a package, or manually adding the angles. It makes use of positioning sloped nodes on lines.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \coordinate (center) at (0,0);
        \coordinate (A) at (1,1);
        \coordinate (B) at (1,-1);

        \draw (B) -- (center) -- (A);

        %% Some parameters:
        \providecommand{\rightAngleMarkSize}{1ex}
        \providecommand{\rightAngleDotSize}{0.5pt}
        \providecommand{\rightAngleDotPosition}{0.55}

        %% Make a rectangle to find some coordinates, e.g. for clipping.
        %% Double size (inner sep) should be enough
        \path (center) --  node (clipper) [sloped,pos=0,inner sep=2*\rightAngleMarkSize,minimum width=0] {} (A);
        \begin{scope} %% limit the clipping to the node with the circle
            \clip (clipper.east) -- (clipper.south east) -- (clipper.south) -- (clipper.center) -- cycle; %% only the part inside this rectangle will be shown
            \path (center) -- %% place the circle on the path, so that it can be [sloped], which enables us to use its center and south east coordinates for further calculation
                node (right angle circle) [pos=0,sloped,circle,draw,inner sep=\rightAngleMarkSize] {} %% this is the actual shown circle, of which ¼ is visible
                (A);

            %% Draw the dot:
            \path (right angle circle.center) -- coordinate [pos=\rightAngleDotPosition] (right angle dot) (right angle circle.south east); %% find the dot's position first
            \path (right angle dot) [fill] circle (\rightAngleDotSize);
        \end{scope}

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Note: I renamed `O` to `center` because I confused it with `0` otherwise.