# Similar Triangle

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to draw something like this in overleaf using Tikzpicture, I need assistance

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Apparently you already (since you are novice here) got two answers, however, in future please always show us, what you try so far and where you stuck in your efforts. Otherwise, your question is of `do-this-instead-of-me" type and will be probably closed as "need details or clarity" ...

Answer (score 1):

This is relative simple problem. You only need to make yourself a little bit familiar with TikZ package. It has very detailed (consequently huge) documentation, but for start is sufficient to read the first *Tutorial* or [A very minimal introduction to TikZ](http://cremeronline.com/LaTeX/minimaltikz.pdf) and see examples of its use [TeXample](https://texample.net/)

With use of the TikZ library `angles` and scale of picture:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
    \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
myangles/.style = {draw, 
                   angle radius = #1 mm},
myangles/.default = 4
                    ]
%%%% first triangle
\draw   (0,0) coordinate[label= left:A] (a) -- 
        (3,0) coordinate[label=right:B] (b) -- 
        (1,2) coordinate[label=above:C] (c) -- cycle;
\pic [myangles]     {angle = b--a--c}; 

\pic [myangles]     {angle = a--c--b};
\pic [myangles=5]   {angle = a--c--b};

\pic [myangles]     {angle = c--b--a};
\pic [myangles=5]   {angle = c--b--a};
\pic [myangles=6]   {angle = c--b--a};
%%%% second triangle: scaled of the first
    \begin{scope}[xshift=44mm, scale=2]
\draw   (0,0) coordinate[label= left:D] (a) --
        (3,0) coordinate[label=right:E] (b) --
        (1,2) coordinate[label=above:F] (c) -- cycle;
\pic [myangles]     {angle = b--a--c};

\pic [myangles]     {angle = a--c--b};
\pic [myangles=5]   {angle = a--c--b};

\pic [myangles]     {angle = c--b--a};
\pic [myangles=5]   {angle = c--b--a};
\pic [myangles=6]   {angle = c--b--a};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Triangles in Tikz}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One solution with `tkz-euclide`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[double distance=3pt]
            \clip(-.5,-.5) rectangle (12,5);
            \tkzDefPoints{-5/0/S,0/0/A,3/0/B,1/2/C}
            \tkzDefPointsBy[homothety=center S ratio 2](A,B,C){D,E,F}
            
            \tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C)
            \tkzDrawPolygon(D,E,F)
            \tkzLabelPoints[left](A,D)
            \tkzLabelPoints[right](B,E)
            \tkzLabelPoints[above](C,F)
            \tkzMarkAngle[size=5mm,mark=|,arc=l](B,A,C)
            \tkzMarkAngle[size=5mm,mark=none,arc=l](C,B,A)
            \tkzMarkAngle[size=5mm,mark=s,arc=l](A,C,B)
            \tkzMarkAngle[size=10mm,mark=|,arc=l](E,D,F)
            \tkzMarkAngle[size=10mm,mark=none,arc=l](F,E,D)
            \tkzMarkAngle[size=10mm,mark=s,arc=l](D,F,E)
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{Triangles in Tikz}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: Similar triangles with tkz-euclide]

Answer (score 0):

Here is something to start with.

How to properly make the right angle mark see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/79999/224762).

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{caption}

\newcommand*{\rechterWinkel}[3]{% #1 = point, #2 = start angle, #3 = radius
    \draw[shift={(#2:#3)}] (#1) arc[start angle=#2, delta angle=90, radius = #3];

}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        
    \begin{tikzpicture}     
    
        \draw (0,0) -- (1,1) -- (3,0) -- cycle;
    \node[xshift=-2mm](A) at (0,0) {A};
    \node[yshift=2mm](C) at (1,1) {C};
    \node[xshift=2mm](B) at (3,0) {B};
    \rechterWinkel{0.2,0}{1}{.2} %A
    
    \rechterWinkel{1,1.05}{-127}{.2} %B
    \rechterWinkel{1,1.04}{-127}{.25} %B

    \rechterWinkel{2.8,0}{90}{.1} %C   
    \rechterWinkel{2.75,0}{90}{.128} %C
    \rechterWinkel{2.7,0}{90}{.155} %C


    

        \end{tikzpicture}

    \begin{tikzpicture}     
    
    \draw (0,0) -- (2,2) -- (5,0) -- cycle;
    \node[xshift=-2mm](D) at (0,0) {D};
    \node[yshift=2mm](F) at (2,2) {F};
    \node[xshift=2mm](E) at (5,0) {E};
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
    \caption{Triangle in Tikz}
    \end{figure}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]